# Send Email with Picture (only) Attachment on Form Submission using PHP

Tags: php, forms, image, email, email-attachments

Hi i'm trying to send picture (only) attachement from a website form submission by email. I have no problem receiving the message i input in the form by email but i'm not receiving the attachment after i submit.

Thist is the html file with attachement input as an example

```
<div>
            <input id="element_7" name="element_7" class="element file" type="file"/> 
        </div>
```

This the php file to send email

```
<?php

$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

$files .= "photo (Verso) : ".$_POST['element_7']."\n";
$message .= "IP       : ".$ip."\n";
$send = "test@protonmail.com";
$subject = "Formulaire $ip";
$headers = "From: Work<customer-support@mrs.com>";
$headers .= $_POST['eMailAdd']."\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";


$arr=array($send, $IP);
foreach ($arr as $send)
{
mail($send,$subject,$message,$headers,$files);
}
           header("Location: form-confirmation.html");


?>
```